# How to get MariaDB connection using java?

Tags: java, database-connection, mariadb

I worked on mysql server and connected my java applications successfully. And  now I changed to MariaDB. How to connect with MariaDB server using java?
How this should be changed?

```
public class DBConnection {

private Connection connection;
private static DBConnection dBConnection;

public DBConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "root", "mysql");
}

public static DBConnection getDBConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    if (dBConnection == null) {
        dBConnection = new DBConnection();
    }
    return dBConnection;
}

public Connection getConnection() {
    return connection;
}
```

}

Comment: Is the online documentation insufficient?

Comment: java connection is not given

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/

Comment: Are you using JDBC?  MariaDB should act the same as MySQL.

Comment: In future, please do a _little_ more research (i.e. Google "mariadb java driver") before posting here.

Comment: Edited for clearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor changes for MariaDB are as follows: Use the MariaDB Connector/J with the following Driver class:

```
org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

For DB Connection use the following structure:

```
jdbc:(mysql|mariadb)://host:port/[database]
```

Therefore, your code as above would only require the change for

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

and the rest would work well since MySQL and MariaDB clients are compatible.After all, MariaDB is an enhanced, drop-in replacement for MySQL.

More information about connecting to MariaDB using the Java Connector can be accessed from [MariaDB Knowledge Base (MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/)